# Product stock not returning to available stock in canceled order

Tags: magento2, product, sales-order, stock, reorder

Is there any explanation of why product stock from canceled order is not returning to available stock?

Step to reproduce:

> 1. I tried to order an item X (until place order)
> 2. Open admin site, edit order (will create a new order and cancel the old order)
> 3. Change the item X to the item Y (assuming that admin recognizes item X is not available).
> 4. At this step, a new order will be created (let's say order #0000001 to order #0000001-1)
> 5. Create an invoice and ship the item.
> 6. Order #0000001-1 status complete and order #0000001 status canceled.

After several steps above I notice that item X stock is not returning after the cancelation process.

I looked into the store configuration and check the setting about "Items' Status to be In Stock When Order is Cancelled" already set to "Yes".

[image]

Any advice or information will be appreciated.

Thank you in advance.